# android show instant time

Tags: android, layout, time, chat

In my chat application, I need to show chat sent/received time below the messages. I use holder to display my messages. How do I include the chat sent/received time along with those? my code is below:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        if(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getId().contains("1"))
        {
            convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_details_view2, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.chat_id=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_details_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.chat_id=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);

            convertView.setTag(holder);


        } 
    } 
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getName());
    holder.chat_id.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getId());

    return convertView;

}
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView timef;
    TextView txt_itemName;
    TextView chat_id;

}
```

Comment: Add a `TextView` to the item layout xml, extend holder and display it? Not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: @zapl please see answers given below,that is what I want. but how can I use it with my holder?can u help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get calender instance like this

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();       
    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
//  second = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);         

    if (c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
        am_pm = "AM";
    else if (c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM) 
        am_pm = "PM";                                   

    if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)
        day = "Sunday";
    else if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY) 
        day = "Monday";
```

send

```
  String send_msg = "send_msg +"\n"+"Send at"+" "+hour+":"+minute+" "+ am_pm+" "+"on"+" "+day;
```

receive

```
  String receve_msg = "receve_msg +"\n"+"receve at"+" "+hour+":"+minute+" "+ am_pm+" "+"on"+" "+day;
```

Comment: thanx.can you please tell what should I use inside the holder given in my code? I mean how can I setText?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Calander for this..

```
 Calender cc = cc.getInstance();
    Date date = cc.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
    String time = format.format(date);
```

Comment: thanx..what should I give inside the holder in my code?how can I setText using holder?